# React Native: Synchronous reducer call, is possible?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm developing a React Native App using Redux and I want to do a simple task:
Collapse or close a search bar of another component depending on the Y position of a ScrollView.

We have a ListView:

```
<ScrollView style={styles.scene} onScroll={(event) => {this.onScroll(event)}}>
```

and this function:

```
onScroll(event) {
        var currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
        var direction = currentOffset > this.offset ? 'down' : 'up';
        this.offset = currentOffset;
        if(currentOffset == 0 && !this.props.isCerca && this.props.textInputTextShop != ""){
            this.props.setCerca(true);
        }else{
            if(currentOffset >50 && this.props.isCerca) this.props.setCerca(false);
        }
}
```

The main problem is that:
When we reach the 0 on the Y (Top of the ListView) the searchbar will be closed BUT if we keep the finger on the screen this event will be fired a lot of times. When we call the function this.props.setCerca(false); the reducer takes time to modify the boolean this.props.isCerca so the searchbar will be collapsed multiple times causing a strange behavior.

How I can set this boolean immediately using redux to returning all the next times without recalling the reducer? Is there a way to "wait" a reducer action? I have to use a local component variable?

Thank you.